# smtp error 534 connecting to gmail python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, ssl, smtp, gmail

I've seen a lot of other posts with the same issue, I tried all of the following:

- allow access to less secure app on gmail
- Unlock token on google
- make an app specific password
- allow IMAP on gmail

Nothing is working, i still get the same error message:

> SMTPAuthenticationError: (534, b'5.7.9 Please log in with your web browser and then try again. Learn more at\n5.7.9  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WebLoginRequired s3sm5978501edm.78 - gsmtp')

This is my code on my python jupiter notebook:

```py
sender_email = "xxx@gmail.com"
receiver_email = "yyy@gmail.com"
password = "xxxxxx"

message = MIMEMultipart("alternative")
message["Subject"] = "new properties for rent"
message["From"] = sender_email
message["To"] = receiver_email

# Create the plain-text and HTML version of your message
text = "Hi, new properties satisfy your search on daft: %s" % dictionary
html = "<html><body>%s</body></html>" % emailBody

# Turn these into plain/html MIMEText objects
part1 = MIMEText(text, "plain")
part2 = MIMEText(html, "html")

# Add HTML/plain-text parts to MIMEMultipart message
# The email client will try to render the last part first
message.attach(part1)
message.attach(part2)

# Create secure connection with server and send email
context = ssl.create_default_context()
with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", 465, context=context) as server:
    server.ehlo()
    server.login(sender_email, password)
    server.sendmail(
        sender_email, receiver_email, message.as_string()
    )
```

Comment: Isn't this due to 2FA/Captcha required IP-address? Which application passwords should solve in all cases except the bad IP-range you're sitting on (Usually caused by shady VPN providers, Tor or any other sort of escape proxy).

Comment: I tried both with and without 2FA what do you mean by bad IP-range?

Comment: This is just a assumption, but here, [read up on the topic](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640?hl=en)

Comment: @Torxed I can't believe it! You're right: I'm in a student accomodation and we share the wiFi, switching to my phone hotspot solved the problem... I waste 3hours for nothing >.<

Post that as an answer if you can :)

Comment: Hehe it can happeh to the best of us ^^ (had the same issue)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a couple of reasons for this.
But since you exhausted most of them, and after talking in the comments. It's clear that you were sitting behind some sort of VPN or shared internet connection.

Some times, logging in on your account in a browser from this VPN/Shared connection would solve the problem. If not, the fastest and easiest way around this is to swap to a single-user connection *(home wifi, dedicated VPS, something where only a handful of users might be sitting)*.

Common issues are: You're using Tor, a popular VPN provider, a school/company network.

Here's more information on the topic:

- https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/86640?hl=en